# python loop thru unstructured data with different possibilities

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been fighting with this problem for a while and would like some help.
I have a plain text data that look like this :

```
(1-3) Apple  

(1) Pear (2) Apple (3) Cherry

(1) Banana (2) Apple

(1-2) Apple  

(1-4) Pear  
...
```

I am reading the data in a loop and I am trying to find an elegant and efficient way of transforming data a list of "Baskets" (max 6 different fruits):

**Basket 1**

```
Fruit1=Apple , Fruit2=Apple, Fruit3=Apple
```

**Basket 2**

```
Fruit1=Pear , Fruit2=Apple, Fruit3=Cherry
```

**Basket 3**

```
Fruit1=Banana, Fruit2=Apple
```

**The question is : is there a Pythonish way of doing this without doing complex IFs statement ?**
The result expected would be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: What is your expected output? A dictionary?

Comment: yes, that would be a list of dictionnaries.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include proper expected output, in the form of list of dicts?

Comment: what would be your expected output if the input is `(1) Pear (2-5) Apple (3) Cherry` ?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: you can have list of dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format is as you imply (a sequence of pairs of tokens, the first either `(N)` or `(N-M)`, the second one any word not containing whitespace)...:

```
import re

list_of_dicts = []
with open('thefile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        d = dict()
        list_of_dicts.append(d)
        tokens = line.strip().split()
        for i in range(0, len(tokens), 2):
            where, what = tokens[i:i+2]
            mo = re.search(r'(\d+)-(\d+)', where)
            if mo:
                start = int(mo.group(1))
                end = int(mo.group(2)) + 1
            else:
                mo = re.search(r'(\d+)', where)
                if mo:
                    start = int(mo.group(1))
                    end = start + 1
                else:
                    msg = 'cannot parse {} in {}'.format(where, tokens)
                    raise ValueError(msg)
            for i in range(start, end):
                d['Fruit{}'.format(i)] = what
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I wanted. I really appreciate. I realize that there is a long way to go to be where you are :-))))